# FindIndependentEdgeSet behaves differently in v9 and v10

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The following code gets different output in v9 and v10.

```
g = Graph[Flatten@Table[Property[l[i] \[UndirectedEdge] r[j], EdgeWeight -> m[[i, j]]], {i, 1, 15}, {j, 1, 15}]];
PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ FindIndependentEdgeSet[g] // Total
```

where the matrix `m` is that in Project Euler Problem 345

In v9 it's 7053 and in v10 it's 13938. (which is the right answer)

Actually, the Document changes as well. In v9 the document gives an example of weighted graph and the function gives the minimal weighted matching while in v10 the document uses a new example and the function gives the maximal weighted matching.

But in the thread of the problem in PE, I find that the following code (by jrp2014) works in v9:

```
Total@FindIndependentEdgeSet@CompleteGraph[{15, 15}, EdgeWeight -> Flatten[m]] /. UndirectedEdge[x_, y_] :> m[[x, y - 15]]
```

Now I am really confused, what is going on indeed in this function?

Comment: Please do not use the `bugs` tag when posting new questions.  It will be added later if people confirm this to be a bug.